# Error Compiling Using Team Build

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, tfsbuild

I'm tring to use Team Build to build a solution.  On my PC I create a new build using VS2008, it only has 1 solution in it.  It's a C++ dll which is compiled in VS2005.  I have the build configured to build on our Build server.  When I run the build I get the error "error PRJ0050: Failed to register output."
When I compile the solution using VS2005 (not using team build) it compiles w/o any errors on both my PC and the build PC.
Why can't I build my solution using team build?
thanks,
John.

Answer (score 1):

You build agent is trying to modify the registry and is unable to do so.

Make sure it runs under a user that has sufficient permissions.

Comment: how do I tell what user the build agent is running under?